# How to load a html page in a jquery dialogbox.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dialog box and i want to load a HTML page into  it h

Comment: Every dialog plugin in jquery has a iframe setting,you can run a html there. Like here http://www.ashishblog.com/ash/dialogUI.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your dialog box is #dialog (`<div id="dialog"></div>`), this would work:

```
$.get("url/to/yourpage.html", function(data) {
    $("#dialog").html( data );
});
```

Comment: ,,Thanks but i have one more query ,,i am not able to open the box more then one time .. once i close it and try to reopen i got error "extensions/schema_generated_bindings.js:662Uncaught Error: "create" can only be used in extension processes. See the content scripts documentation for more details.".. what to do now.. my script is"function pass_url(url)
 {
  $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
   $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
   
   $('.dialog').load(url);
return false;   
  
 });
 }"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
var url = "the url";
var dialog = $("#dialog");
if ($("#dialog").length === 0) { // only create if it doesn't exist
    dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>').appendTo('body');
}
// load remote content
dialog.load(
url, {}, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    dialog.dialog({
        // your options
    })
}​)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you've already created the dialog, loading and opening then become as simple as:

```
$('#dialog').load( url, function(){
    $(this).dialog('open');                   
});
```

Comment: @charlitetfl Thanks but i have one more query ,,i am not able to open the box more then one time .. once i close it and try to reopen i got error "extensions/schema_generated_bindings.js:662Uncaught Error: "create" can only be used in extension processes. See the content scripts documentation for more details.".. what to do now.. my script is"function pass_url(url)
 {
  $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
   $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
   
   $('.dialog').load(url);
return false;   
  
 });
 }"