# How to open .cfm page in JQuery dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, dialog

I have a link on my page where user can click and open another page. My current code open this page in another tab. So I would like that to be done in JQuery dialog box. User can click on the link and open the page without opening a new window. I already placed my div on the bottom of my current page and set the id to dialog. Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <a class="nav" href="procedure.cfm" target="_blank" style="color:red" onClick="verifyProcedure()">Procedure for use</a>
</div>
```

```
function verifyProcedure() {
    document.getElementById("submitForm").disabled = false;
    var contentUrl = 'procedure.cfm' 
    var dialog1 = $("<div>").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      close: function (e, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
      buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
    });
    dialog1.load(contentUrl).dialog('open');
}
```

Code above doesn't work the way I want to. My page still gets open in new tab. I want dialog box to pop up on the same page with content of my procedure.cfm page. Can anyone help me how to get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486624/how-to-load-a-html-page-in-a-jquery-dialogbox

Comment: I tried that code and did not work for me. Page was not open in dialog box.

Comment: `dialog()` is part of jQuery UI. Have you loaded the required jQuery UI files before you are attempting to use it?

Comment: I checked and some files were missing from JQuery UI. Now works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone know why my background is not disabled? I used modal and is set to TRUE. That should disable background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove href and target from link

```
<a class="nav" href="javascript:void(0)" style="color:red" onClick="verifyProcedure()">Procedure for use</a>
```

Comment: This is an error that I get after I click on the link: TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function var dialog1 = $("<div>").dialog({

Comment: make sure you have jquery.ui JS

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

Comment: JQuery UI was the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also make sure the page you want to open is added to your js.

Comment: How I can disable background behind Dialog box? Once I click the link and open dialog box I want everything else disabled.

Comment: Develop that code as a separate function.  Once you have working, call it from the verifyProcedure function.

Comment: modal:true will disable background , make sure your you have opacity and z-index on  .ui-widget-overlay class of jquery.ui.css ,or make it manually on page wilth 
.ui-widget-overlay{ opacity:1; z-index:1000;}